# Get back HP apps after reinstalling Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, reset

My HP 15-r036tu Notebook had many useful softwares (PowerDVD, Youcam, HP Support Assistant etc.) preinstalled with Windows 8.1. Now I have upgraded to Windows 10 and there are a few issues. So I would like to reset Windows 10.

1. Will these apps stay after resetting?
2. Is it possible to reinstall them after resetting. Note that many of these are not free softwares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset option will not remove the HP apps if you choose the "Restore Factory Settings" option.
[image]

[See section "Reset your PC"](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options)